# .NET to Rails (Want to move from .net to rails)

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

I have been a .NET developer for the last 7 years. Now I want to move to a Ruby on Rails stack.

Also, I don't have any experience with Linux.

Anybody else who made the same move? Any suggestions? Good books?

I am having some idea about ASP.NET MVC

Comment: why are you moving, if you have no idea about platform? What are arguments?

Comment: @Andrey: short of money perhaps? requirements from a new employer?

Comment: Grab a virtual machine (VirtualBox for example) and install Linux. Switch to fullscreen and try to work a few days in that. Should teach you a lot already.

Answer (score 2):

First, check out the RoR site.  If you haven't done ASP.NET MVC, or are unfamiliar with MVC, it's going to be a big difference.  Rails is a BIG MVC framework, so it may do a lot of "magic" stuff that you are unsure about (but so does .NET).

I'd suggest reading about MVC first if you are unfamiliar about it, then go from there.  It might be worth it checking out another lightweight framework first, as some people have issues jumping right into a big MVC framework.

Good luck!  I've found Ruby to be a lot of fun.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already know Ruby? If not, "[Why's (poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/)" is a humorous, but educational read.

You should also check out [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/), if you want some insight into the Rails framework.